# How to disable permanently WiFi Broadcom in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've a Samsung laptop that has wifi board from broadcom that is known for being a crap.
I bought an usb wifi module and wanted do disabble the built-in forever.
Need help with this in Ubuntu 19.10.

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom.conf`

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist bcma-pci-bridge


01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [185f:04db]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: the easiest way is to disable it in BIOS.

Comment: I've been looking for it but seems that this bios do not allow it

Comment: You can blacklist all Broadcom modules: `b43`, `bcma` and uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` if installed.

Comment: Can you help with the commands?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: 1:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [185f:04db]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
 Kernel modules: bcma

Comment: So blacklistng should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can blacklist Broadcom kernel modules.

Run in a terminal `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom.conf`

Add there

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist bcma-pci-bridge
```

Save by Ctrl+O and exit by Ctrl+X.

Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot.

Comment: Done what you said but wifi still working after rebooting.

Comment: the output of the sudo modprobe -r bcma is:
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcma is in use.

Comment: Please post the output of the same command again. We'll see.

Comment: Maybe add there `bcma-pci-bridge` too

Comment: added but it stills works after reboot

Comment: Are you sure that the path was correct? Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom.conf` and the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to your question.

Comment: blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist bcma-pci-bridge

and

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4357] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. BCM43225 802.11b/g/n [185f:04db]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
 Kernel modules: bcma

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll update the answer.

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u` is needed.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for the help Pilot6

Comment: Don't forget to accept the question.